# Why am I getting a syntax error when executing multiple update statements in one call with Go's mysql driver?

Tags: mysql, go

Currently, here is the code:

```golang
func TestExec_Directly(t *testing.T) {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "my_dsn/order_detail_db_0")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    res, err := db.Exec("UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_0` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_1` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_2` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);",
        112, "King", "James", 123, 11, 112, "King", "James", 123, 11, 112, "King", "James", 123, 11)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    t.Log(res.RowsAffected())
}
```

And I got the error:

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_1` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`' at line 1
```

Notice that it says near **UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_1`**.

And then I try this:

```sql
BEGIN;UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_0` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_1` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);UPDATE `order_detail_db_0`.`order_detail_tab_2` SET `item_id`=?,`using_col1`=?,`using_col2`=? WHERE (`order_id`=?) OR (`item_id`=?);COMMIT
```

I got the same error.

And I doubt that Go my-driver has some bug. And then I try the same query in Python, I still got the error.

So maybe this is not a bug?

However I run the query via mysql-cli, it looks good.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nWPZ.png)

And how to make the Go code works as expected?